# Why did the Sith want to build the Death Star if "The ability to destroy a planet is insignificant next to the power of the Force."?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader, sith, death-star

I've heard explanations like Tarkin wanted it and presented his plans to the emperor. And I've heard the comment by Vader was more for the audience, since Luke does destroy the Death Star using the force at the end (and #2 does "kill" the emperor also). But did the Sith justify it to themselves as necessary somehow (like they didn't need it but were too busy/lazy to do all that the Death Star could)? Or was Vader BS'ing when he said that? Or was it presented to the emperor and he was like, "sure, why not", being fairly indifferent to it, and/or figuring he might as well enjoy the fear it would instill?

Comment: I don't have a canon quote for it, but it's basically what Tarkin says: it's an instrument of intimidation (which is why they needed to fire on a well-known planet).  Vader (or especially the Emperor) may be more powerful, but a distant Emperor on his throne is not as viscerally terrifying.

Comment: Ok so it's the appearance mostly (and the Sith couldn't handle the multitasking), since people weren't aware of how powerful the dark side of the force is. Or so they thought. I'm wondering what the Sith point of view was, compared to what Tarkin said.

Comment: There were no "Sith" making a collective decision here.  It was the emperor's choice, and from *Return of the Jedi*, it is very clear that the emperor makes consistent use of both the Force and his conventional resources.

Comment: I was wondering what each thought, not necessarily in agreement. I see they make use of what they can. But why did they want to bother if they thought it was insignificant?

Comment: In some works, death and fear strengthen the Dark Side. Whether that's the case here *shrug*

Comment: And if the reason was appearance and instilling fear, couldn't the dark side (somehow) do this better also (or one would think they would think so), whether people were aware it was or not?

Comment: You could have asked why the empire has stormtroopers, star destroyers, and TIE fighters using the same logic. Vader isn’t trying to say the Death Star is useless. He’s just responding to the claim that the Death Star was “the ultimate power in the universe”. It’s like, “ok the Death Star is great but it’s not literally the greatest, you know”. Also, just because something isn’t the best doesn’t mean it’s useless. Why use **only** the force to rule the galaxy? Why not use the force plus a huge space station plus a bunch of starships and soldiers, etc.?

Comment: I don't know, "insignificant" is a pretty strong word to compare with. I'm just wondering about their justifications in light of that, not for others' justifications. One might think that they think they could just use the force to control everyone, if they're so good at the dark side, I'm not sure. I'm asking about the Death Star specifically because of this specific comment. And it taks a lot of resources to build it, one might think they would prefer to divert resources elsewhere if it were insignificant.

Comment: It’s not insignificant. It’s insignificant **compared with the power of the force**. He’s not saying the Death Star is useless. He’s saying that’s how awesome the force is. Also maybe he’s being slightly poetic and exaggerating. It’s just as likely that if Darth Vader we’re emperor, he *wouldnt* have built the Death Star, but palpatine is in charge and he sees the value of it, even if Vader doesn’t.

Comment: Even in relation, still, it does take a lot of resources for something that's insignificant by comparison to something they already have available to use. And yes, I'm wondering about each of their reasonings.

Comment: A rifle is insignificant compared with the power of a thermonuclear weapon. Why does the US still have Marines? Same reason. You can’t use the most powerful thing for all situations. And the one most powerful thing can’t be everywhere and do everything at once. It’s starting to feel more like this is a personal criticism of Star Wars and not a question from curiosity, because instead of considering these reasonings, it seems to me like you’re simply rejecting all of them. It also seems like you’re talking Vader’s comment as imperial policy, which it clearly is not.

Comment: I'm not looking for other peoples' opinions here, I'm not looking for policy, I'm looking specifically for the Sith's views. Clearly a rifle serves a different purpose than a bomb. I'm not trying to speculate on what he meant, I'm asking about what they specifically said about their thoughts.

Comment: I think Vader's opening line to Tarkin is too important to be omitted, `Don't be too proud of this technological terror you've constructed.` It seemed to me Vader was speaking more to bring Tarkin's mood down and remind everyone there's a bigger bad, not to say it wasn't an impressive technological terror.

Comment: Palpatine's obsession with superweapons is his Achilles Heel and persistently the cause of his downfall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're hearing in this scene is *Vader's* opinion. By comparison, Palpatine seems overwhelmingly in favour of **mechanical terror weapons** to try to control the galaxy. This is his fifth attempt (that we know of) in canon.

- Army of millions of droids
- Death Star
- Death Star II
- Starkiller Base
- Xyston-class Star Destroyers

Answer (score 4):

The evidence of why is in Motti's reply to Vader's statment.  From the [Episode 4 script at IMDB](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

```
                VADER
    Don't be too proud of this
    technological terror you've
    constructed. The ability to destroy
    a planet is insignificant next to
    the power of the Force.

                MOTTI
    Don't try to frighten us with your
    sorcerer's ways, Lord Vader. Your
    sad devotion to that ancient religion
    has not helped you conjure up the
    stolen data tapes, or given you
    clairvoyance enough to find the
    Rebel's hidden fort...
```

Motti isn't cowed by things he can't see or hear, such as The Force.  His response to the idea of The Force is scorn and defiance, insulting the Emperor's apprentice.  The Force may be overwhelmingly powerful, but the mere idea of it doesn't succeed in curbing Motti's attitude.  He needs a physical demonstration.

The Death Star is a physical and palpable expression of the Empire's power, to persuade citizens/subjects like Motti.  And to warn those who feel more defiant than Motti and would join the rebellion.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to unpack here; first off Tarkin didn't come up with the idea for the weapon, he just co-opted and took credit for it once it was clear the thing was finally working as advertised.
The initial weapon design was commissioned by Sidious himself, and started under the auspices of the Separatists, before shifted over to the Republic during the war, and then of course the Empire. It's implied it's at least inspired but stories of ancient Sith weapons of terror powered by giant kybers (the one on Malachor likely among them) if not directly based on actual surviving plans.

It's function for the Empire was purely meant to be a means of exerting control through terror. It's no coincidence that Palpatine finally dissolved the Senate and put the regional military governors in direct control of their respective systems just as soon as the station was operational. He felt he no longer needed to bother with the bureaucracy to maintain control once he had the power to obliterate any planet that defied Imperial rule.

As for the force; well of course the force is always going to be more powerful. It's an effectively infinite, omnipresent energy field that transcends time and space. The likely reason Sidious didn't think that mattered is because he was confident in being one of only two left that could actually use it in any meaningful way. But as Luke would later observe; his over confidence was his weakness. After all it wasn't a weapon meant to defeat force wielders, it was meant to bring the galaxy to heel.

Enjoyment isn't really a factor here. Evil people are generally by their very nature fearful and are thus seeking greater and greater degrees of control and dominion. This is just one of many ways in which Palaptine sought to impose his will on the galaxy.